# how to disable ScrollView clipping content in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I need that red rectangle should be visible until reach to the leading or trailing edge of the device.
So the problem is scrollview cliping red boxes (hiding) as move beyond the scrollview container size.
code:

```
struct test: View {
var body: some View {
    ScrollView(.horizontal,showsIndicators:false) {
        LazyHStack{
            ForEach(0...4,id:\.self){i in
                Rectangle()
                    .fill(Color.red)
                    .frame(width: 60, height: 50, alignment: .center)
            }
        }.padding(.horizontal, 4)
    }.background(Color.yellow)
    .frame(width: 68, height: 60, alignment: .trailing)
}
```

}

Results:
[image]

Expected:(I also produce this result by setting `ScrollView` full width  and adding padding (`.padding(.horizontal, UIScreen.main.bounds.width/2 )`) to `LazyHStack`)
But it is a hack by adding space at start and end, and problem remain unresolved, that is clipping of `ScrollView` content

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I'm not exactly sure what the problem is, but you probably want the `padding` to be on the `Text` and not the `ScrollView`. Correct me if this isn't what you are looking for.

```
struct test: View {
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(.horizontal) {
            Text("Hello, World!")
                .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, alignment: .leading)
                .padding(.horizontal, 40)
        }
        .background(Color.yellow)
    }
}
```

Result:

[image: "Hello, World!" in scroll view, offset 40pts right. Scrollview takes up entire screen width.]

Comment: No, as I mention in the question I need scrolling from 40 offset from leading edge

Comment: @Amir can you clarify what do u mean by "scrolling from 40 offset from leading edge"?

Comment: if you run the code in the question you will see start point of the scrolling, while any other layouts like `HStack` by default does not clip their content

Comment: @Amir the "Hello World" is touching the leading edge of the scroll view. So you want to offset it by 40pts right, so that there's a space on the left?

Comment: Yes exactly, I added this 40pts space added as per requirement, but content clipped by scrollview unfortunate

Comment: @Amir but the clipping only happens on scroll, which is normal...

Answer (score 3):

in iOS 17, now ScrollView supports that feature:

```swift
ScrollView {
   ...
}
.scrollClipDisabled()
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be working for me when I remove the line: `.frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, alignment: .leading)`.
On an iPhone XR, I'm seeing a horizontal ScrollView with a yellow background starting at 40 offset from leading and ending at 40 offset from trailing. Is this what you're trying to achieve?
Also, I'm pretty sure `UIScreen.main.bounds.width` is going to return the width of the device, which will be a problem if you want your text to take up 80 pixels less than that value (since your ScrollView has 40 padding either side).

Comment: my purpose is to start and end scrolling at center of screen as above in expected demo, but content show visible all over screen

Answer (score 0):

if I understand correct from your answers, this is the result you want:

```
    struct test: View {
    var body: some View {
         GeometryReader { geo in
             VStack {
                 Spacer()
                 HStack {
                     ScrollView(.horizontal,showsIndicators:false) {
                        LazyHStack{
                            ForEach(0...4,id:\.self){i in
                                Rectangle()
                                    .fill(Color.red)
                                    .frame(width: 60, height: 50, alignment: .center)
                            }
                        }
                        .padding(.horizontal,40)
                    }
                    .background(Color.yellow)
                    .frame(width: geo.size.width, height: 60, alignment: .center)
                 }
                 Spacer()
             }
        }
    }
}
```

Result:
[image: screenshot]